# Momentum dependence of Fourier amplitudes in the Fourier expansion of relativistic classical fields

Tags: quantum-field-theory, notation, classical-field-theory

A relativistic classical field $\phi(x)$ can be decomposed into Fourier modes as $$\phi(x)=\int\frac{d^3\textbf{p}}{(2\pi)^{3/2}\sqrt{2E_{\textbf{p}}}}\Big(a(\textbf{p})e^{-ip\cdot x}+b^*(\textbf{p})e^{+ip\cdot x}\Big)$$ where $x\equiv x^\mu=(t,\textbf{x})$ and $p\equiv p^\mu=(E_\textbf{p},\textbf{p})$. I have a very basic question regarding the notation. Why is this Fourier amplitudes $a(\textbf{p})$ and $b^*(\textbf{p})$ are functions of 3-momentum $\textbf{p}$ instead of the 4-momentum $p$. I have also seen the notation $a(p)$ and $b^*(p)$ in the literature. Now it confuses me.

Comment: because $p^0(\boldsymbol p)=\sqrt{\boldsymbol p^2+m^2}$...

Comment: As @AccidentalFourierTransform said, this is due to the fact that classical particles are "on the mass shell," as we usually say. The fact that $m^2=E^2-\mathbf{p}^2$ means that only certain $(E,\mathbf{p})$ combinations are allowed (namely, those lying on a particular hyperbola) for a classical particle of a given mass; specifying $\mathbf{p}$ for a given $m$ therefore also fixes $E$.

Comment: @probably_someone That clarifies my confusion. :-)

Comment: @SRS Cool, I've made this an answer, then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @AccidentalFourierTransform said, this is due to the fact that classical particles are "on the mass shell," as we usually say. The fact that $m^2=E^2-\mathbf{p}^2$ means that only certain $(E,\mathbf{p})$ combinations are allowed (namely, those lying on a particular hyperboloid) for a classical particle of a given mass; specifying $\mathbf{p}$ for a given $m$ therefore also fixes $E$.